# Validate spring context without refreshing it

Tags: java, spring

Say I have a Spring `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` instance that was not refreshed yet, such as:

```
try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()) {
  context.register(Config1.class);
  context.register(Config2.class);
  context.register(Config3.class);
  context.register(Config4.class);
  // ...
}
```

Is there a (runtime during a unit test) way to "validate" it - i.e. make sure all beans *can* be wired as expected from Spring's perspective at least - without refreshing it? That is, make sure there are no missing or duplicate beans, misspelled properties, circular dependencies, etc. without actually instantiating any of the beans?

In essence, I'm looking for a way to - at least logically - make all bean definitions be mocked, i.e. some equivalent of:

```
@Bean
public SomeBean1 someBean1(SomeBean2 someBean2) {
  return mock(SomeBean1.class);
}

@Bean
public SomeBean2 someBean2(@Value("${someProperty}") someProperty) {
  return mock(SomeBean2.class);
}
```

though I don't necessarily need it done in the above way obviously.

Comment: What about checking this in the project duplicate with using a test of context loading?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. As I need 17 more characters, the long answer is also: No.